# Data dump restore though pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin

I have backup file in *.backup format. When I am trying to restore i through pgAdmin in postgres db it's giving me error -
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive.

No sure how to restore the dump. In pgAdmin I am just right clicking on dg and selecting restore and then browsing the path of backup file.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do it by importing the backup using psql:

```
psql --host localhost --port 5432 --username "username" --dbname "database"  < backup.backup
```